# problem with moving the humanoid through a touched event

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm doing a cutscene and I'm interested into moving the humanoid through a script when a part is touched.

This is my code:

```
game.Workspace.SpawnLocation.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
local humanoid = hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
humanoid:MoveTo(Vector3.new(41.958, 4.264, 66.435))
end)
```

However the script is not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right off the bat I see that you did **NOT** include a end to mark the end of the script. This script will sometimes fail, so I recommend you add FindFirstChild().

Fixed Version:

```
   workspace.SpawnLocation.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
     local humanoid = hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")

     if not humanoid then
       return
     end

     humanoid:MoveTo(Vector3.new(41.958, 4.264, 66.435))
    end)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I did a silly mistake. Thank you again for pointing out my mistake, have a nice day!

Comment: @alisa Sorry I came off a little rude. You too!

Comment: Also, make sure to keep your output window open. It will tell you errors and sometimes how to fix them.

Comment: Oh, you wasn't rude at all! Interestingly, I had the window open but no errors was appearing which is strange but thank you for solving my  problem! I'll mark your answer as the solution as soon as the 6 mins limit passes. Have a nice day, once again! :)